# Generate regex for exact words from a list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex that can match any word in the following or similar words. `*` in these strings are exact `*` and not any character.

```
Jump
J**p
J*m*
J***
***p
J***ing
J***ed
****ed
```

I want to keeo the length fixed.

```
1. Any string of lenght 4 that matches the string 'jump' 
2. Any string of length 6 that matches 'jumped' 
3. Any string of length 7 that matches 'jumping'
```

I was using the following statements but for some reason, i am not able to to the correct translation. It accepts other strings as well.

```
p = re.compile('j|\*)(u|\*)(m|\*)...)
bool(p.match('******g'))
```

Comment: How about `"Jump|J\*\*p|J\*m\*|...|J\*\*\*ed"`.

Comment: Try going here: http://regexstorm.net/tester or to another testing website, put all the strings that should match and some that shouldn't, and then test your regex.  When you write `*`, I think you might mean `.` (any single character).   You might even mean `\w` (any word character).  Maybe start with `(J\w\wp|J\wm\w)`

Comment: Does your "*" represent _any single character_? If so, then it must be a ".".

Comment: sorry, `*` is exact charcter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward regex. We want to match a word, but allow each character to be an asterisk. The regex is therefore a sequence of character groups of the form `[x*]`:

```
[Jj*][u*][m*][p*](?:[i*][n*][g*]|[e*][d*])?
```

[See it in action at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/bOoGpW/2)

If you only want to match these exact words, make sure to use the pattern with [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch).

Comment: Nice!  And `*` doesn't require escaping because of the enclosing `[]`, I assume?

Comment: Should `****`, `******`, and `*******` be considered valid matches?

Comment: @zzxyz Correct. Most characters lose their special meaning inside a character class.